# After accept permission how to open a activity?

Tags: java, android, permissions

I trying to do a simple functionality. After the user accept permission for camera i need to open a new activity, but how do this?

This is a code. I check the permission and the request it. On my else if i open a new activity.

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @OnClick(R.id.scanButton)
    void scanZxing(View view) {
        if(getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(context, "We need permissions to acces your CAMERA!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ((MainActivity) context).checkCameraPermission();


        } else if (view.getId() == R.id.scanButton) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScanBarcodeActvity.class);
           startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
       }
    }

@TargetApi(23)
public void checkCameraPermission(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        return;
    }
    if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[]
        grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks for your permission", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "We need your permission to open camera",
                        LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `checkCameraPermission()`. Well what are you doing there? We can't see.

Comment: I did put the intent, below the code in your `checkCameraPermission()` method.

Comment: That code will only be called if you have already the permission. You are suggestion that you have not permission yet.

Comment: Updated with checkCameraPermission() method. So how to do both of this in one click. I open the barcode, then i got permission request and if i accept i automatically open new Activity?

Comment: `requestPermissions()` What are you doing in that function? We cannot see! you are requesting the user for permission? Did you ever get an answer?

Comment: Yes i got and save permission in OnRequestPermissionResult.

Comment: You are saving a permission? How? For what? `"Thanks for your permission"`. Well there you can start your activity! Add those two intent lines there.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the permission request result in your activities `onRequestPermissionsResult` methodm and if user granted the permission then open the activity

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA &&
            grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //permisssion was granted
    } else {

        //permisssion was not granted
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting a comment as answer. You can see it here too.

Answer (score 1):

I am supposing you want to open ScanBarcodeActvity.

you can do it in following way

```
public void openScanBarCodeAcitvity() {

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScanBarcodeActvity.class);
               startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Call above method at following place in addition to scanZxing() method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[]
        grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks for your permission", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 //permission granted, open activity
                 openScanBarCodeAcitvity();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "We need your permission to open camera",
                        LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting a comment as answer. You can see it here.